# TypeError: Cannot call method "push" of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

I am attempting to modify a google-apps-script to create an event in google calendar to follow up on emails with certain labels. That side of it I will take care of. The issue I'm having is getting TypeError: Cannot call method "push" of undefined when attempting to run the script. I am not seeing the mistake here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 function ReadEmails() {

  var thread, subject, body, from, 
      date, emails, index, event = [], i;

  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  var LABEL = mySheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var TOTAL = mySheet.getRange("D7").getValue();

  emails = GmailApp.search("label:" + LABEL);  
  var count = emails.length;

  if (count == 0)
    return;

  if (count > TOTAL) 
    index = getIndex(TOTAL, 0, count);
  else {    
    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
      index.push(i);
  }

  for (i=0; i<TOTAL; i++) {

    var n = index[i];

    if (emails[n]) {

      thread    = emails[n].getMessages()[0];

      subject   = thread.getSubject();
      body      = processHTML(thread.getBody(), 250);
      link      = thread.getId();
      from      = thread.getFrom();
      date      = Utilities.formatDate(thread.getDate(), 
      Session.getTimeZone(), "MMM dd, yyyy");
      event     = 'Follow up with' + from + 'on'+ subject + ', Next Friday 
      at 1PM';

    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventFromDescription(event);
    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());

    }
  }



}  

function getIndex(count, min, max) {
    var results = [], index;
    while ( count > 0) {
        randNumber = Math.round(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
        if (results.indexOf(randNumber) == -1) {
            results.push(randNumber);
            count--;
        }
    }
  return results;
```

Comment: It means that `index` is undefined. You call `index.push()` without initializing `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pointy pointed out, the value of `index` is undefined. Actually, all of your variables `thread, subject, body, from, date, emails, index, event` are undefined at first, since you're assigning two values to them, which I have never seen in any language reference.
Later, you're re-assigning all of them except `index`, but the initial assignment of `[], i` is syntactically wrong - hence the `undefined`.

Just declare and initialize `index` like this: `var index = [];` and you should be fine.
The other variables you could initialize to `null` to make clear that you're gonna assign some proper values later on.